# Undefined method 'set_cookie' for capybara How can I create a cookie?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am running against a public site

When I try `set_cookie` I get:

```
undefined method 'set_cookie' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x531e792e4b07692c browser=:chrome>

require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'pry'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com/'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

root='/'

describe 'Form flow works', :type => :feature do

  before :each do
    Capybara.current_driver = :chrome
  end 

  it 'Collect the customer data', :happy do
    visit( root )
    page.driver.browser.set_cookie('test_disabled', 'true', :domain => 'www.google.com')
```

---

None of the current answers on SO address my issue or have worked.
Actual url is not google.

I tried `show_me_cookies` but that didn't work - details:
Added the gem:
`$ gem install show_me_the_cookies
Successfully installed show_me_the_cookies-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for show_me_the_cookies-4.0.0
Done installing documentation for show_me_the_cookies after 0 seconds
1 gem installed`

I added the following code to the spec (just using 1 file with all code right now)

```
RSpec.configure do |c| 
  c.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  c.include ShowMeTheCookies, :type => :feature
end
```

and then i added show_me_the_cookies in my spec but all I got was `...spec/foo_spec.rb:17:in`block in ': uninitialized constant ShowMeTheCookies (NameError)`

Comment: try this actually: https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies

Comment: Thanks@BKSpurgeon Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Capybara doesn't provide a cookie API because it's main aim is testing apps, and setting cookies when directly when testing is generally not a good idea.  That being said, it sounds like you're scraping the web rather than testing so you have 2 options.

1. Access the driver specific cookie methods.  Since you're using the Selenium driver that would be something like

   ```
   page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(name: cookie_name, value: cookie_value)
   ```
2. Use a gem that provides a common cookie API across different drivers. That would be the `show_me_the_cookies` gem recommended in the comments.  That would then be

   ```
   create_cookie(cookie_name, cookie_value)
   ```

You may be getting uninitialized constant because you need to `require 'show_me_the_cookies'` in your spec_helper/rails_heper

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

After visit to create the session I used:

```
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
browser.manage.add_cookie :name => 'ab', :value => 'true', :expires => Time.now + 3600
```